# Calculation of exponential of momentum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, mathematics

I'm puzzling out the way one can determine $exp(iA)$ operator for an unbounded $A$. More precisely I would like to know, how could I deal with the *momentum operator* $p_x = -i\hbar\partial_x$.

I'm trying to follow the instruction which I learned from Frederic Schullers lectures (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GbqA9Xn_iM0 lecture 10 and 11)

The instruction is as following:

1) Construct the positive real-valued measure $\mu_{\psi}$ using *Stieltjes inversion formula*:

$\mu_{\psi}((-\infty,\ \lambda]) = \lim_{\delta\to 0^{+}}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^{+}}\frac{1}{\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\lambda+\delta}dt \ Im<\psi, R_p(t + i\epsilon)\psi> $, where $R_p(z)$ is a resolvent operator.

2)Construct complex-valued measure $\mu_{\psi, \phi}$ by polarization formula:

$\mu_{\psi, \phi}(\Omega) = \frac{1}{4} [\mu_{\psi+\phi}(\Omega) - \mu_{\psi-\phi}(\Omega)+i\mu_{\psi-i\phi}(\Omega)-i\mu_{\psi+i\phi}(\Omega)], \Omega$ is a Borel set in $\mathbb{R}$

3) Construct projection-valued measure $P$ as following:

$<\psi, P(\Omega)\phi> := \int \chi_\Omega d\mu_{\psi, \phi}$

4) Calculate the integral:

$exp(i\hbar\partial_x) := \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\lambda}\ P(d\lambda)$

**My achievments are**
really poor. Actually, I've just calculated the resolvent for the momentum operator:
$R_p(z) = \frac{i}{\hbar} \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}dt\ e^{izt\hbar^{-1}}u(t)$, where $u(t)\psi(x) = \psi(x-t)$.
But I got in trouble even at the first step while calculating Stieltjes integral. I've achieved such thing to calculate:

$\frac{i}{h}\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}da\ e^{iza\hbar^{-1}}\ \int_{\mathbb{R}} dx\ \psi^{*}(x)u(a)\psi(x)$ and I don't know how to deal with it.

Maybe someone tried this way and can give me some advices?
However, I bet it is not the shortest way to rigorously construct exponential of unbounded operator. Are they any other ideas to define exp? 
If they are, what is the main purpose of the spectral theorem and all of equastions I mentioned before. It seems to be not constructive in this case.

Comment: would SE Mathematics be better?

Comment: Well, indeed. However,  I suppose there are some physicists who tackled somehow this problem. Actually, any quantum mechanics starts with this exponential operator, and one would like to know how to operate with it.

Comment: I dunno about "any quantum mechanics" but *many* quantum mechanics texts simply defines the exponential of an operator in terms of the series of the exponential.  Clearly you want something much more sophisticated than this.

Comment: the definition of the exponential of an unbounded operator cannot be given through the power series, at least not for the whole of the space.

Comment: one should consider the exponential mapping in the differential geometric sense instead

Comment: However, usually in physics, one deals with subspaces of the whole hilbert space, where the power-series expressions are valid. I was wondering, what kind of problem do you have such that the power series expressions are not valid ? it would be useful to add some context on this point.

Comment: @QCrypt Agreed that a physical context is missing as it is clear the OP wants the math rather than the physics version of events.

Comment: well, i kind of disagree: imo, the question is quite deep and important. In my understanding, the OP is an example of situation where the presice implications in physics are intimately related to the precise mathematical understanding. For example. various QFT models utilize representations defined on the whole of the hilbert space rather than a dense subspace (which is typical of elementary QM models).

Comment: OP should check the standard references: Reed and Simon (volumes I and II), Hall (Quantum Theory for Mathematicians), etc.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to derive that this exponential function is an translation operator.

Comment: What was [good for Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator) who first noticed it, a formal rewriting of the Taylor series, should be adequate for most physics usages... You want a functional analytic answer, well, that's what MathSE specializes in.